# Returning strings in PERL

Tags: perl, soap

I am trying to get SOAP to return a message, at the moment it just returns hello world.

```
package RAM;
sub ram {
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Sys::MemInfo qw(totalmem freemem totalswap);

return SOAP::Data->name('result')->type('string')->value("hello world");
}
1;
```

I am trying to get SOAP to return:

```
print "free memory:  ".(&freemem / 1024)."\n";
```

instead of "hello world"

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Bruce Thanks, but it didnt work, got the same error: SOAP::Serializer::envelope: Server Usage: Sys::MemInfo::freemem() at /etc/perl/RAM.pm line 5.

Comment: Your original question never mentioned an error. If you are getting an error then please specifiy that in the question.  I suggest you edit the question to provide more information about the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about....

```
  my $string_to_return = "free memory: ".(&freemem / 1024)."\n";
  return SOAP::Data->name('result')->type('string')->value($string_to_return);
```

Comment: Bad style to use ampersands in front of method calls *unless* you want to pass `@_` to the subroutine you are calling. This is Perl 4 "Cargo Cult"